# Npm audit issue, keeps getting error again and again

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-audit

Keeps getting this issue, in my new github repo, cleaned cache, again installed npm but nothing seem to work now, what should i do? how can i fix this?

even if i do npm audit fix it return with the following code again and again.

```
up to date, audited 1778 packages in 13s

49 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

31 vulnerabilities (24 low, 3 moderate, 4 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to worry about. essentially what is happening is that there are some problems in the packages you're using.
essentially if you update them, they'll break something else so they're frozen in place unless the maintainers fix it.
if you want you can fix them yourself, but it is generally too much effort. nothing you can do about it except wait until they're fixed, that is, if the maintainers decide to fix them

Answer (score 0):

Some of the errors require manual debugging and can't be fixed by npm itself. So you need to fix the issues yourself.

Comment: well i tried updating the packages it having issues with but its still same.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with [npm-force-resolution](https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions) package

Add resolutions section with vulnarable dependency

```
"resolutions": {
  "lodash": "^4.17.5"
}
```

Then run

```
rm -r node_modules
npx npm-force-resolutions
npm install
```